# Using Transitions on Ember

Tags: ember.js, css-transitions

I have been using jquery plugins to create transitions on my views, and have decided to create them at the CSS level with classnames.

I would like to receive feedback/opinions about which could be most suitable way to integrate transitions at the view level.

Option 1)

```
App = Em.Application.create({

  customEvents: {
    webkitTransitionEnd: 'transitionEnd'
  }
});

Em.View.extend({

  transitionEnd: function(event) {
    // write you APP logic. TransitionEnd will fire multiple times for each transitioned CSS property
  },

});
```

Option 2)

```
Em.View.extend({

  transitionEnd: function(event) {
    // write you APP logic. TransitionEnd will fire multiple times for each transitioned CSS property
  },

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();

    self.$().on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(event) {
      self.transitionEnd(event);
    });

  })

});
```

Any opinions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I am thinking about the same thing right now.  I think Option 2 would be better.  I don't see why we would want to create a custom event, when there is already an event fired from the browser.  But I'm rather new to Ember, so I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: @gstroup, below my last approach. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i added webkitTransitionEnd event to be managed by the eventDispatcher and using it on the following way:

```
Yn.Modal = Em.Mixin.create({

  isHidden: true,
  classNameBindings: ['isHidden'],
  classNames: ['modal'],


  transitionEnd: function(event) {
    // transitionEnd fires multiple times

    if ( event.originalEvent.propertyName === '-webkit-transform' ) {
      var eventName = this.get('isHidden') ? 'transitionHide' : 'transitionShow' ;
      this.fire(eventName);
    }

  }

});
```